# Time comparison: Map vs. List comprehension for input in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to find which input method is faster for a list of integers in Python and it's my first time using the **timeit** module. Here is my code:

```
from timeit import timeit


A = "from sys import stdin"

func1 = '''
def read() -> list[int]:
    return [int(x) for x in stdin.readline().split()]
'''
func2 = '''
def read() -> list[int]:
    return list(map(int, stdin.readline().split()))
'''

print(timeit(setup=A, stmt=func1, number=10000))
print(timeit(setup=A, stmt=func2, number=10000))
```

If I run it, this is my output:
**0.00350099999923259 0.0055315999779850245**

Here the first method (func1) seems to be faster

but if I repeat:
**0.009563300001900643 0.006233800027985126**

Now it's the opposite. Am I doing something wrong or is there a logical interpretation for these results? I'm using Python 3.10.0.

Comment: You're timing how long it takes to define the functions, instead of actually calling them.

Comment: @Jan Wilamowski I see... so I need to find the right way to measure the time. Thank you!